# JS Show field when checked

Tags: jquery, checkbox, field, javascript, show

How do i show an input field if #tryout checkbox is checked.

I already have this which hides 2 fields, now i want to show 3 new fields..:

```
$('#tryout').click(function () {
    $('#title').toggle(!$(this).attr('checked'));
    $('.navn').toggle(!$(this).attr('checked'));
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chain your selectors in this case:

```
$('#tryout').click(function () {
    $('#title, .navn').toggle(!$(this).attr('checked'));
    $('#newfield1, #nf2, #nf3').toggle($(this).attr('checked'));
});
```

Comment: hmm, it works, but it still shows from the beginning. Should i set the input type to hidden?

Comment: @Azzyh - Whatever you don't want show from the start, use `style="display: none;"` on.